# Unique hints for TCheckListBox items?

Tags: delphi

How can I show a hint that is specific to the item under the mouse as a user moves their mouse down a list of items in a TCheckListBox?

In Delphi 2010.

Tom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `TCheckListBox` with four items called "alpha", "beta", "gamma", and "delta" (for instance). Then do

```
const
  CheckListBoxHints: array[0..3] of string = ('first hint', 'second hint', 'third hint', 'fourth hint');

var
  prevIndex: integer = -1;

procedure TForm1.CheckListBox1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
var
  index: integer;
begin
  index := CheckListBox1.ItemAtPos(point(X, Y), true);
  if index <> -1 then
    CheckListBox1.Hint := CheckListBoxHints[index]
  else
    CheckListBox1.Hint := '';
  if index <> prevIndex then
    Application.CancelHint;
  prevIndex := index;
end;
```

end;

Answer (score 6):

The way I do this is to make use of the `TApplication.OnShowHint` event. This allows you to customise the `HintStr` parameter and in you can do this based on the position contained in the `HintInfo` parameter.

As Remy points out in the comments, you can also handle `CM_HINTSHOW` to achieve the same effect and this can be cleaner to implement in some ways if you are already subclassing the standard VCL controls.

I have implemented a interface based framework to make use of this throughout my app. Basically in `TApplication.OnShowHint`, `HintInfo.HintControl` is asked if it supports this interface. If so then it is given an opportunity to customise the hint text. It works beautifully.

Basing hints off raw `MouseMove` events works perfectly well but it seems a little wasteful to call ItemAtPos on every `MouseMove` event rather than waiting until it's actually time to show the hint. That's why I have a slight preference for the approach described above.

Comment: Using `TApplication.OnShowHint` is the correct way to do it (even better, derive a new component from `TCheckListBox` and have it respond to the `CM_SHOWHINT` message). In addition to what David said, the `HintInfo` can be customized to specify which area of the control the current `HintStr` should apply to. That way, when the mouse moves out of this area, a new `OnShowHint` event (or `CM_SHOWHINT` message) occurs, even if the mouse is still over the same control.

Comment: +1. Well, I think that my code makes the control *feel* just right, but your method seems better nevertheless.

Comment: @Remy I think you mean `CM_HINTSHOW` in fact. You are right that `CM_SHOWHINT` could work too, I just felt that `TApplication.OnShowHint` felt somehow more public!

Comment: @David: Hm... I don't quite get the objection about the "feeling". You have tried my code, right?

Comment: @Andreas no, I was misunderstanding what you had done. It feels perfect the way you suggest. I'll edit my post. It seems wasteful to update the hint on every mouse move rather than just when its time to show the hint.

Answer (score 1):

There's only one way I know of - doing it the hard way...

You can query the element the mouse is hovering over and set the hint like this:

```
procedure TForm2.CheckListBox1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
var hintItem : Integer;
    point    : TPoint;
begin
     point.X := X;
     point.Y := y;
     hintItem := CheckListBox1.ItemAtPos(point,true);
     if hintItem >= 0 then begin
        CheckListBox1.Hint := CheckListBox1.Items[hintItem];
        CheckListBox1.ShowHint := true;
     end else begin
        CheckListBox1.Hint := '';
        CheckListBox1.ShowHint := false;
     end;
end;
```

A little more tweaking would make it even more elegant. I for one would only *hide* the hint on MouseMove and start (or reset) a timer to redisplay it. So it will appear when the mouse didn't move for a while and will immediately disappear when you start moving the mouse.

This would be the behaviour one expects from windows. My implementation as given above will be kind of unusual, because the hint stays visible even if you move your mouse. This is because the mouse doesn't leave the element (TCheckListBox).

Oh, another thing: You should also make the hint disappear on MouseLeave.

Comment: Right. +1 for being better than mine :-)